# (Pentaho PDI):Thread: Couldn't find starting point in this job

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

**Pentaho running job through command line**

I have a pentaho job which runs successfully in pentaho but if i try to run the same through command line i get the error -(But It runs Successfully in one PC throws, error in another PC)

**Here is my problem of the moment**:

2016/12/12 16:52:30 - Start of job execution

2016/12/12 16:52:30 - ERROR (version 6.0.0.0-353, build 1 from 2015-10-07

13.27.43 by buildguy) : A serious error occurred during job execution:

2016/12/12 16:52:30 - **Couldn't find starting point in this job**.

2016/12/12 16:52:30 - ERROR (version 6.0.0.0-353, build 1 from 2015-10-07

13.27.43 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleJobException:

2016/12/12 16:52:30 - **Couldn't find starting point in this job**.

2016/12/12 16:52:30 -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:532)

2016/12/12 16:52:30 -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:435)

2016/12/12 16:52:30 - Kitchen - Finished!

2016/12/12 16:52:30 - Kitchen - ERROR (version 6.0.0.0-353, build 1 from

2015-10-07 13.27.43 by buildguy) : Finished with errors

2016/12/12 16:52:30 - Kitchen - Start=2016/12/12 16:52:15.536, Stop=2016/12/12 16:52:30.652

Comment: Are you sure you are running kjb file in both machines?

Comment: Yes, I am same kjb file

Comment: I have the same error. I am running a KJB file with one KJR file in it. The KJR runs fine by itself. The KJB throws this error. Anyone find a fix?

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same issue (9.1), but it disappeared after I deleted the "Start" step and replaced it with a new one. Looks like the "Start" step *must* be named "Start", so NO renaming it, even if it is allowed...

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you trying to run a KTR file instead of a KJB?

Take a look:

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?58160-Couldn-t-find-starting-point-in-this-job

Answer (score 1):

you should try pan, pan is PDI command line tools.

[PDI Command line tools](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Products/Data_Integration/Command_Line_Tools)

```
sh /home/patel/Downloads/pdi/pdi-ce-9.0.0.0-423/data-integration/pan.sh /file:/home/patel/Documents/replication.ktr
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if you are using ****Start**** step while writing a job.
P.S. Each Pentaho job needs a start step to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Claus's answer is right,if you rename you "Start" model,you should useing normal name "Start",I use this method fixed my problem.